# How to pad multiple images to the minimum shape containing them all?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function to load and process data for NN. 
As input I have a set of pictures of different sizes. The pictures should be represented as 3D numpy array with RGB channels. I need them to be of the same size (the size of the biggest of the pictures).

I've tried `np.pad` but it seems like I didn't get the idea how it should work. And actually even I'd got the padding, I don't know how to change it depending on the size of the picture. Here's the code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os


def load_data(path):
    aminoacids = ['Ala','Arg','Asn','Asp','Cys','Gln','Glu','Gly','His','Ile', 'Ini', 'Leu','Lys','Met','Phe','Pro','Pyr', 'Sec','Ser','Thr','Trp','Tyr','Val']
    matrix = []
    answer_labeled = []
    names = os.listdir(path)

    for i in names:
      matrix = cv2.imread(path + i, 1)
      matrix = np.pad(matrix, (0, 1), 'constant', constant_values=[255,255,255])
      for y in aminoacids:
        if y + "-" in i:
          a = [matrix, y]
          answer_labeled.append(a)
    return answer_labeled
data_processed = load_data("/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/dl/img/ans/")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-e021738e59ea> in <module>()
     20     return answer_labeled
     21 
---> 22 data_processed = load_data("/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/dl/img/ans/")
     23 
     24 # print(len(os.listdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/dl/img/ans/")))

<ipython-input-50-e021738e59ea> in load_data(path)
     13     for i in names:
     14       matrix = cv2.imread(path + i, 1)
---> 15       matrix = np.pad(matrix, (0, 1), 'constant', constant_values=[255,255,255])
     16       for y in aminoacids:
     17         if y + "-" in i:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.pyc in pad(array, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
   1208                 kwargs[i] = _as_pairs(kwargs[i], narray.ndim, as_index=True)
   1209             if i in ['end_values', 'constant_values']:
-> 1210                 kwargs[i] = _as_pairs(kwargs[i], narray.ndim)
   1211     else:
   1212         # Drop back to old, slower np.apply_along_axis mode for user-supplied

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.pyc in _as_pairs(x, ndim, as_index)
    951     # Converting the array with `tolist` seems to improve performance
    952     # when iterating and indexing the result (see usage in `pad`)
--> 953     return np.broadcast_to(x, (ndim, 2)).tolist()
    954 
    955 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.pyc in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    180            [1, 2, 3]])
    181     """
--> 182     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
    183 
    184 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.pyc in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    127     it = np.nditer(
    128         (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
--> 129         op_flags=[op_flag], itershape=shape, order='C')
    130     with it:
    131         # never really has writebackifcopy semantics

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,) and requested shape (3,2)
```

Of course I tried to google this error but didn't find something useful or understandable for me (because I'm really new in programming). I'd appreciate any help and ideas.

Comment: The error does not appear to be complete, or related to the code you posted.

Comment: It is complete and related, I edited the post (error is appearing while using the function)

Comment: @LisaGrigorashvili No, it is not complete. The details are hidden in `4 frames`. You should be able to click there and get the full trace. That is what MadPhysicist's comment is pointing at. Given that there is no simple way to reproduce your problem without you sharing your input, it would make it much simpler for other to help you with this.

Comment: Basically, you have a list of arrays of shape `(x_i, y_i, 3)` and you want them to be reshaped to `(max(x_i), max(y_i), 3)`. Is that correct?

Comment: I think yes, that's correct. Just to be clear: if I have an array with the shape ```(72, 72, 3)```, I want it to be reshaped to ```(92, 92, 3)``` and these additional arrays should be ```[255, 255, 255]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had to solve a similar task, so I created the following function for it. It allows to specify the fraction of the size difference for each dimension, that should be padded before and after (similar to `np.pad`). For example if you have two arrays of shape `(3,)` and `(5,)`, then `before=1` would pad the whole difference (in this case `2`) on the left whereas `before=0.5` pads one element on the left and one on the right. Similar to `np.pad` these factors can be specified for each dimension as well. Here is the implementation:

```
import numpy as np


def pad_max_shape(arrays, before=None, after=1, value=0, tie_break=np.floor):
    """Pad the given arrays with a constant values such that their new shapes fit the biggest array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arrays : sequence of arrays of the same rank
    before, after : {float, sequence, array_like}
        Similar to `np.pad -> pad_width` but specifies the fraction of values to be padded before
        and after respectively for each of the arrays.  Must be between 0 and 1.
        If `before` is given then `after` is ignored.
    value : scalar
        The pad value.
    tie_break : ufunc
        The actual number of items to be padded _before_ is computed as the total number of elements
        to be padded times the `before` fraction and the actual number of items to be padded _after_
        is the remainder. This function determines how the fractional part of the `before` pad width
        is treated. The actual `before` pad with is computed as ``tie_break(N * before).astype(int)``
        where ``N`` is the total pad width. By default `tie_break` just takes the `np.floor` (i.e.
        attributing the fraction part to the `after` pad width). The after pad width is computed as
        ``total_pad_width - before_pad_width``.

    Returns
    -------
    padded_arrays : list of arrays

    Notes
    -----
    By default the `before` pad width is computed as the floor of the `before` fraction times the number
    of missing items for each axis. This is done regardless of whether `before` or `after` is provided
    as a function input. For that reason the fractional part of the `before` pad width is attributed
    to the `after` pad width (e.g. if the total pad width is 3 and the left fraction is 0.5 then the
    `before` pad width is 1 and the `after` pad width is 2; in order to f). This behavior can be controlled
    with the `tie_break` parameter.
    """
    shapes = np.array([x.shape for x in arrays])
    if before is not None:
        before = np.zeros_like(shapes) + before
    else:
        before = np.ones_like(shapes) - after
    max_size = shapes.max(axis=0, keepdims=True)
    margin = (max_size - shapes)
    pad_before = tie_break(margin * before.astype(float)).astype(int)
    pad_after = margin - pad_before
    pad = np.stack([pad_before, pad_after], axis=2)
    return [np.pad(x, w, mode='constant', constant_values=value) for x, w in zip(arrays, pad)]
```

For you example you can use it as follows:

```
test = [np.ones(shape=(i, i, 3)) for i in range(5, 10)]
result = pad_max_shape(test, before=0.5, value=255)

print([x.shape for x in result])
print(result[0][:, :, 0])
```

This produces the following output:

```
[(9, 9, 3), (9, 9, 3), (9, 9, 3), (9, 9, 3), (9, 9, 3)]
[[255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]]
```

So we can see that each array has been padded symmetrically to the shape of the largest array `(9, 9, 3)`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be very helpful, I will try to implement it in my code. Additional thanks for comprehensive and full answer, it is really good for me as for newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `np.pad()` is actually quite well [documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

An example that would work for 3D data with the numbers you provided is:

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (72, 72, 3))

new_arr = np.pad(
    arr, ((0, 92 - 72), (0, 92 - 72), (0, 0)),
    'constant', constant_values=255)

print(new_arr.shape)
# (92, 92, 3)
```

---

## EDIT

To solve the full problem, you need to first determine your max sizes and then pad all the other images accordingly.
The [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/) package provides you with a number of functions to get the job done more easily (Disclaimer: I am the main author of it).

---

If you can fit all your images in memory, the simplest approach would just be to use [`fc.extra.multi_reframe()`](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus/src/e02a1493ddc9c8fb6f6ec9efa7ea1b0ab62f20c7/flyingcircus/extra.py#lines-5797), i.e.:

```
import flyingcircus as fc


new_arrs = fc.extra.multi_reframe(arrs, background=255)
```

---

If you cannot fit all the data into memory, you should do this in two-passes, one to compute the minimum shape fitting all your inputs and then perform the actual padding with [`fc.extra.reframe()`](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus/src/e02a1493ddc9c8fb6f6ec9efa7ea1b0ab62f20c7/flyingcircus/extra.py#lines-5797):

```
# assume your data is loaded with `load(filepath)`
# ... and saved with `save(array, filepath)`

# : first pass
shapes = [load(filepath).shape for filepath in filepaths]
target_shape = tuple(np.max(np.array(shapes), axis=0))

# : second pass
for filepath in filepaths:
    arr = load(filepath)
    new_arr = fc.extra.reframe(arr, target_shape, 0.5, 255)
    save(new_arr, filepath)
```

---

Internally, `fc.extra.reframe()` is using `np.pad()` (or something similar to that but faster) and it is roughly equivalent to:

```
def reframe(arr, target_shape, position=0.5, *args, **kws):
    source_shape = arr.shape
    padding = tuple(
        (int(position * (dim_target - dim_source)),
         (dim_target - dim_source) - int(position * (dim_target - dim_source)))
        for dim_target, dim_source in zip(target_shape, source_shape))
    return np.pad(arr, padding, *args, **kws)


reframe(arr, target_shape, 0.5, 'constant', constant_values=255)
```

note that the `position` parameters determines where the array is places with respect to the new shape. The default value of `0.5` would make place all images in the center, while `0.0` or `1.0` would push it to one side or the other of the new shape in all axes.
The FlyingCircus version of it is a bit more flexible in that you can specify a `position` value for all axes separately.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it must be helpful, I'll try to use it. But I'm sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what "If you can fit all your images in memory" mean. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I assume you are familiar with the concept of "disk" (hard drive) and "memory" (RAM) and that `size(memory) < size(disk)`. When you `load()` the data from disk, you are effectively copying information into memory. If you do this multiple times you use more and more memory. Since, typically, the memory is much smaller than the disk, you may end up in a situation when you are trying the load more data than your memory could fit. In your case, for performing the padding you do not need all the images loaded into memory and hence you can still perform the resize even if the images you are...

Comment: ...processing are larger than what your memory can hold. The downside of this is that you are using `load()` twice as many time as strictly required and that can limit your execution speed since the `load()` operation can be *relatively* expensive. That being said, `1000` (one thousand) images of size `100 x 100` (with 24-bit color depth) would require only ~3.6 MB of memory while your computer is likely equipped with GBs of memory. But `10000000` (ten million) images would require ~35GB of memory and that would likely be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for a expanded answer and your help, got it.